# POST on ModelViewSet with nested object Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, post, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm building an API with the django rest framework. I have these models:

```
class Organisme(models.Model):
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    adresse = models.ForeignKey(Adresse, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Adresse(models.Model):
    rue = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
```

This is the view for my mode **Organisme** :

```
class OrganismeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Organisme.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrganismeSerializer
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter, DjangoFilterBackend)
    filter_class = OrganismeFilter
    search_fields = ('nom')
```

And my serializer:

```
class OrganismeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Organisme
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1
```

So I'm trying to create a new **Organisme** by sending this:

```
{
    "adresse": {
        "rue": "test"
    },
    "nom":"TestTest",
}
```

or

```
{
    "adresse": pk_id,
    "nom":"TestTest",
}
```

But I always end up with this error:

```
IntegrityError at /organismes/
(1048, "Column 'adresse_id' cannot be null")
```

If you guys know how to proceed... Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to override `create` method to make [writable nested serializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers):

```
class AddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Addresse
        fields = ('rue',)

class OrganismeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    addresse = AddressSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Organisme
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        address_data = validated_data.pop('adresse')
        address = Adresse.objects.create(**address_data)
        organism = Organisme.objects.create(address=address, **validated_data)
        return organism
```